# Profile Roaming, to make not to copy all the files to the local PC

Tags: active-directory, roaming-profile

Active Directory supports so called, Profile Roaming.

With this, ideally, you could logon from any Domain joined PC and have your files.

BUT, with Profile Roaming, Domain Computers tries to download ALL the profile files.

What if user has tons of files in his "My Documents" ? It would simply kill the network.

How to prevent Domain Computers downloading all the files?
May be there are a workarounds?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Roaming Profiles are the devil incarnate... **kill it**... ***kill it with fire***...

Okay, mildly over dramatic. However, I find that roaming user profiles take up enormous disk space and really slow down logon/logoff times. What you probably want to look at is Desktop and My Document redirection via Group Policy. It will automatically point the folders to a UNC path. You can keep the roaming profiles if needed.

In small networks, I combine this with domain based DFS so that if the servers have to change at a later date, I don't have change the GPO

Answer (score 4):

This is achieved using [folder redirection](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Folder_redirection), where you stipulate that the my documents folder (for example) resides on a network device.